# convert array element from string to number

Tags: php, arrays, string, numbers, json

I've some numbers which come from a query and that I have to represent using the json_encode function.
Everything work but the output looks like this

```
{ "label": "man", "data":[["0","1.13"], ["1","1.38"], ["2","1.87"], ["3","1.12"], ["4","1.28"]]}
```

so I think that the problem is that all the numbers are stored as string.
Is there a function to convert all the elements in number?

Comment: `"so I think that the problem is that all the numbers are stored as string."`  What problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to add JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK to your [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function:

```
   json_encode($array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: Just FYI, this was added in PHP 5.3.3.

Comment: @Rocket I know, just want to let him know the options available.

Comment: Glad I could help. You can mark the answer as correct if you want

Answer (score 1):

You can get the integer or float value of a variable with this:

```
echo (integer)$variable;
echo (float)$variable;
```

Comment: That's good if I'll use the echo instead of using the json_encode...thanks everybody for the answers!

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$json = '{ "label": "man", "data":[["0","1.13"], ["1","1.38"], ["2","1.87"], ["3","1.12"], ["4","1.28"]]}';

$structure = json_decode($json, true);
$newData = $structure['data'];

for ($x=0;$x<count($newData);$x++):
    for ($i=0;$i<count($newData[$i]);$i++):
        $newData[$x][$i] = (float)$newData[$x][$i];
    endfor;
endfor;

$structure['data'] = $newData;
print json_encode($structure);
```

New Result:

```
{"label":"man","data":[[0,1.13],[1,1.38],[2,1.87],[3,1.12],[4,1.28]]}
```